# Avoid generation of declaration files for tests

Tags: typescript, webpack

I am using webpack and typescript, and I have two folders, src and test.

I am writing a typescript library, so I want to ship it with the declaration files for my source code (so in my tsconfig.json I have declaration: true).
However I don't want to ship the declaration files for my tests.

If I exclude the test folder in my tsconfig.json, then my IDE will give me stupid errors in the test files for packages it cannot find.

If I include them, it seems that there's no way to specify to only generate declaration files for the src dir, and not for the test dir, neither in the tsconfig.json nor in the webpack config. Therefore declaration files for my tests end up in my dist/test folder (at least not in the bundle.js itself).

One solution could be to run a task/script after the webpack bundle to clean up the dist/test folder, but ideally I would prefer to avoid an extra step only to do this.

Is there any option/config that I am missing?

I think it should be pretty straightforward to not want to generate test files declarations....

Answer (score 0):

> I think it should be pretty straightforward to not want to generate test files declarations....

- Webpack should exclude the test files (recommend node to test your files)
- Your ide should have compile on save set to false.

Comment: if I use the exclude option of the loader but i don't exclude them in tsconfig.json the test files get generated anyway. The only way as written above is to exclude them in the tsconfig.json, but at that point they don't work well in the ide.

I do want/like that the ide checks my test files for errors, removing it it's not an option...